# microsoft jscript runtime error object expected

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Please help me for resolving the jquery error.

```
$('#<%=drpMasters.ClientID%>').change(function () {
        $('#divLeadSource').css("display", "none");
        $('#divAccount').css("display", "none");
        $('#divContact').css("display", "none");
        $('#divLeadStatus').css("display", "none");
        $('#divSupplier').css("display", "none");

        var element = $(this).find('option').filter(':selected').val();

        switch (element) {
            case "1":
                $('#divLeadSource').css("display", "block");
                $('#<%=lblQuickHead.ClientID%>').val("New Lead Source");
                break;
            case "2":
                $('#divAccount').css("display", "block");
                $('#<%=lblQuickHead.ClientID%>').val("New Account");
                break;
            case "3":
                $('#divContact').css("display", "block");
                $('#<%=lblQuickHead.ClientID%>').val("New Contact");
                break;
            case "4":
                $('#divLeadStatus').css("display", "block");
                $('#<%=lblQuickHead.ClientID%>').val("New Lead Status");
                break;
            case "5":
                $('#divSupplier').css("display", "block");
                $('#<%=lblQuickHead.ClientID%>').val("New Supplier");
                break;
            default:

        }

    });
```

Comment: Please help us first by telling us what exactly the problem is. Any more details in the error message?

Comment: Run the code in browser with JS debugger like Firefox or Chrome and see what line is causing this error. Without it, we're in the dark here.

Answer (score 0):

The "object expected" error usually means that you have a stray comma somewhere but I don't see how that could be your problem here. The only possibility I can see in your code is this:

```
switch (element)
```

If this chain

```
$(this).find('option').filter(':selected')
```

doesn't find anything then you'll end up with `element` having an `undefined` value and IE may be upset that you are trying to `switch` on an undefined value.

This is my best guess without a functional example.